# Why AppBar's automaticallyImplyLeading has no effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Has no impact of true/false
  title: Text('AppBar'),
)
```

[Docs mention](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html):

> automaticallyImplyLeading: If true and leading is null, automatically try to deduce what the leading widget should be. If false and leading is null, leading space is given to title.

In my code, `leading` is `null` but setting `automaticallyImplyLeading` property has no effect on the title. But docs say something else.

Comment: automaticallyImplyLeading is used for removing back button

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @jitsm555 Why that property isn't working according to what the docs say?

Answer (score 2):

`automaticallyImplyLeading: false` used for removing the back button, from the second screen(This comes when the user navigates from the first screen to the second screen, which is the flutter default behavior). To show back button/leading widget flutter occupy some space at the left side of AppBar.

**If false and leading is null, leading space is given to title.**

As per the above statement, if it is false then, the default space of the leading widget/back button given to the title widget of App Bar.

```
appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Remove back button
        title: const Text('This is simple Text of App Bar for second screen'),
      ),
```

With `automaticallyImplyLeading: false,`

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `automaticallyImplyLeading` only works when a route has been pushed onto the navigator?

Comment: Personally, I never found any usecase other than that